# How do you determine current directions in a circuit with multiple voltage sources?

Tags: electric-circuits

is there a method to determine the current directions for a circuit where there are multiple voltage sources?
thanks

Comment: It's pretty hard to answer this without a diagram of an example.  The answer is Yes, with Kirchoff's voltage and current laws

Comment: yes thank you. but i have another Q. if I decompose a circuit into two circuits and work out the current through a wire according to both decompositions, but the current direction is the opposite in each, then do I need to subtract the currents ?